# fetch method javascript passthrough cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api

I have a request that I'm making via `fetch(url)`. It doesn't seem like my cookies that I have are being passed along?

What is the canonical way of doing this? Should I pass `document.cookie` to the `fetch` request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`credentials: 'include'`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#example-xhr-credentials) in the init object you pass as the second arg to `fetch(…)`:

```
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `credentials` in the options object passed to the second parameter:

```
fetch('url', {
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

`credentials` also takes `same-origin`, which only sends cookies which match the domain of the URL requested.